# Get min and max of unsorted list

Tags: sorting

I am hypothetically given an unsorted list of x numbers and I would like to find the min. and max. numbers in the list.

Now based on the research I have done the most efficient sorting method seems to be quick sort.

Comment: Is sorting a requirement? Because you don’t have to sort the data to find these 2 values, just do a linear traversal and keep track of min and max values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting is at best an O(N log N) operation. In order to sort a list, you have to look at each value at least once O(N)

It would be faster to just loop through the array and keep track of the smallest, and biggest numbers

```
        int[] unordered = { 5, 9, 4, 2, 6, 4 };
        int min=0, max=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < unordered.Length; i++)
        {
            if (min > unordered[i]) min = unordered[i];
            if (max < unordered[i]) max = unordered[i];
        }
```

Comment: In C# you can just use the “Array.Sort” method and pass in the array you want to sort. Then you can simply access the 0 index and last index for the min and max.

Comment: Quick sort and merge sort have the same runtime O(N log N). Merge sort is more stable but takes more space. Insertion sort is slowest at O(N ^2) but takes the least space. You can find many implementations of quicksort and merge sort on github. https://github.com/BotJeff/ProgrammingLessons/blob/master/Algorithms/Sorting/Quick.cs

Comment: Yeah that’s pretty much it

Comment: Faster without sorting, make sure to review asymptotic analysis.

Comment: The act of sorting has to go through the list at-least once (could be more) plus the overhead of swapping items, by iterating and keeping track of the min and max you only go through the list exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to sort the values and get the first and last indexed values - the following simply iterates over the array of numbers and checks against the minNum and maxNum values and sets / resets those accordingly.

```js
let numbers = [10,7,4,6,3,77,232,56,99];
let minNum = numbers[0];
let maxNum = numbers[0];


numbers.forEach(function(number) {
  if(number < minNum ) {minNum = number};
  if(number > maxNum ) {maxNum = number};
})

console.log(minNum) // gives 3
console.log(maxNum) // gives 232
```